# given a list of strings tell tensorflow to create a new one from learned of other strings?

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I have the following list thousands of strings like this:

```
gabaybagxppppapppx5qvxdncxcyPcxvNcPNxPPPdPxgaBQaBag
gcyvgxpppvNppxab5nxdpvbxvBaPvqxBQPvPvxP5PPxgN5y
gabcygxpppaBpapxab6xnvPdxvpcqaxvQvNvxPdPPPxgNvgaya
gvnagyaxappbvppxapapdxcPpqanxvBcPaxvPdPxPPaNaPayxgvQagNa
cqagayxvpdpxapapBgpaxpvPpcxvPnPcx5PPaxPPaQvyax5gag
6yaxpppvpppx8xvnvyaPxvPvPaPxvBpgcxPPdgaxdggv
gncgyaxp5ppxvp5xcPpbvxvq5xaQ6xPPPBvPPxgcyaNg
NabydxppapaQppx8xvb5xcncqx8xPPPvgPPxgNBagBya
8xvpcNax6pax5PBaxppvgnvx7yxPapvyaPxcgd
gabayangxpvpapppxnvBdxapaNPNaPx6PaxcPaQvxPaPaycxq5ba
```

How can tensorflow be trained to create a new one from learned?
Im using Jupyter Notebook with python 3

Answer (score 2):

You should look into generative models.

1) Why are you intent on using tensorflow? There are non-DL generative models that **MIGHT** work here

2) What exactly are those strings? What do they mean? To me, they look like random noise.

Comment: Hi Ian, These strings are encoded maps from a game I made... thats way I need some machine learning or IA that undestands the pattern and can create new maps with some logic.. and not just random